# Error when installing "Windows Management Framework 5.1" on Server 2012 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

In order to install `NuGet` on a server I tried to install WMF 5.1 on Windows Server 2012 R2:

I go to this page: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616 to install it.

It worked on another server with the same version (actually I believe it's a clone of the VM of that other server, so I'm assuming they're somewhat identical).

When I run this installer (which I also ran on the working one)
`Win8.1AndW2K12R2-KB3191564-x64.msu`

I get the following error message in a dialog box..why would this be if it worked on the other server?

```
[Window Title]
Windows Update Standalone Installer

[Main Instruction]
Windows Update Standalone Installer

[Content]
The update is not applicable to your computer.
```

Output of `$PSVErsionTable.PSVersion`

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

Output of `$PSVersionTable`

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.19170
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Answer (score 1):

WMF 5.1 may be already installed. You can check this with Powershell:

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
```

The "Major" and "Minor" values reflects the WMF version

If WMF 5.1 is not already installed on the server, check that you are running .NET Framework 4.5.2 b[ecause it's a requirement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/setup/install-configure)

Comment: I added the output of your suggested command to my answer.

Comment: Can you confirm that you installed .net 4.5.2 or greater ?

Comment: No, because I don't know how...I ran the Powershell version thing, and I posted the results above.  I don't know what version it would be if it was installed and what version it would be if it was not installed.

Comment: I also looked in the list of installed programs and did not see `Microsoft .net 4.5.2` listed, but I did see `.net Core` or something like that.  I know the application uses `.net Core` as a dependency.

Comment: So, per this document (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed) it looks like it is installed as my release key is `0x0070805 (460805)` which is higher than `378389` which is mentioned in the documentation listed in this sentence.